# "Real" MVC pattern with Scala and JavaFX with multiple views and controllers

Tags: java, scala, javafx, model-view-controller

I'm building a scala desktop app, requirements are:

- Java 8 **(not 9, not 10, not 7)**
- Using Scala (eventually with Java)
- MVC Patter (View and Controller must be "platform" independent, my teacher has already a working console and Swing view, but tell us nothing)
- The View implementation must be on JavaFX

I can't use ScalaFX, Swing (Java) nor Swing (Scala).

In main main, from now `MyAwesomeApp` I made:

```
class MyAwesomeApp extends Application {
  override def start(primaryStage: Stage) {
    // Stuff here
  }
}

object MyAwesomeApp extends App {
  Application.launch(classOf[MyAwesomeApp], args: _*)
}
```

Now pick three generic views: `MainMenu`, `SettingsMenu`, `NewGameMenu`, `GamePanel`.
As you can imagine, at the start the application will launch with the `MainMenu`, having two buttons that can bring to `NewGameMenu` and `SettingsMenu`. Then in the `NewGameMenu` there will be a button that brings me to `GamePanel`.

For each of this I'll have a controller: MainMenuController, SettingsMenuController, NewGameMenuController, GamePanelController. But this controllers are independent from the platform: in other words **there are not JavaFX controllers**. Why? Because JavaFX controller "can see" all components of the view, such as TextBoxes, Buttons etc, and can just "load" them with the `@FXML` tag. This is not my case, since I must be "View Independent", so I think about a wrapper and an Observer pattern.

I came up with the `FXControllers` (JavaFX controllers) and `Observers` (real MVC controllers). Every FXController will have an Observer that implements his trait (=interface). This is some code:

This is a helper object to load an fxml

```
object ViewLoader {
  def loadView(controller: GenericFXController[_], layoutPath: String): Pane = {
    val loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass.getResource("/layouts/" + layoutPath))
    loader.setController(controller)
    loader.load()
  }
}
```

A generic FXController will have this (I used a generic type "A", since I know that every FXController will have an observer, but I don't know which one):

```
abstract class GenericFXController[A] (private val path: String) {
  protected var observer: A = _
  protected val layout: Pane = ViewLoader.loadView(this, path)

  def setObserver(observer: A): Unit = {
    this.observer = observer
  }

  def getLayout: Pane = layout
  def getPaneType: SceneType.Value = paneType
}
```

And finally a defined FXController for the MainMenu:

```
class MainMenuPaneFXController extends GenericFXController[MainMenuObserver](path = "MainMenu.fxml") {
  @FXML protected var startNewGameBtn: Button = _
  @FXML protected var settingsBtn: Button = _

  this.startNewGameBtn.setOnMouseClicked(_ => {
    this.observer.onStartNewGameBtnPressed()
  })
  this.settingsBtn.setOnMouseClicked(_ => {
    this.observer.onSettingsPressed()
  })
}

trait MainMenuObserver {
  def onStartNewGameBtnPressed()
  def onSettingsPressed()
}
```

Now the controller, simplified:

```
class MainMenuObserverImpl extends MainMenuObserver {
  override def onStartNewGameBtnPressed(): Unit = println("Start pressed")
  override def onSettingsPressed(): Unit = println("Settings pressed")
}
```

I have a view wrapper that hides JavaFX behind a trat and class.

```
trait GenericView {
  def showView(): Unit
  def closeView(): Unit
  def isShowing: Boolean

  def setScene(sceneType: SceneType)
}
```

Where SceneType is a simple "Enum" that has voices like "MainMenu", "SettingsMenu" etc.

In the main method I start the view

```
   val view: GenericView = new ViewFX(primaryStage)
```

## ...And now how to pass "Observers" to "FXControllers"?

I can add methods to the GenerView trait, but it must remain "platform independent", so I can't return a JavaFX Scene or a Swing Button. The view cannot istantiate controller classes: should have a ".setObserver(), and `FXControllers` are, in some way, part of the view.

Should I create every single Scene in the ViewFX, and set the controller for everyone at the creation? How to pass the view to controllers (and the GenericView for changing scenes)?

My apps used to be simple: one screen, one controller. In this case how can I proceed in an ELEGANT way, without "cheating"?

Comment: Didn't really read it, just skimmed through... Too much "hell" and bold font, you might consider toning it down a little bit.

Comment: usually, the model is an observer and any views and controllers are passed a reference to the model.